# Angular Nested Router Outlets with Lazy Loaded Modules

Tags: angular, routes, nested, router-outlet

I am trying to create a router-outlet inside another router-outlet to service as sub navigation, but tried the below and its not working

[image]

**HomeComponent**:

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**MainRouting/AppRouting**:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'properties', loadChildren: () => import(`./properties/properties.module`).then(m => m.propertiesModule)}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

**PropertiesComponent**

```html
<button [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { properties: ['searchproperties'] } }]">Search Properties</button>
<router-outlet name="properties"></router-outlet>
```

**PropertiesRouting**:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PropertiesComponent},
    { path: 'searchproperties', loadChildren: () => import(`./searchproperties/searchproperties.module`).then(m => m.SearchpropertiesModule), outlet: "properties"},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
  
export class PropertiesRouting { }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code in stackblitz?

Comment: You can just have your `PropertiesComponent` have an unnamed routeroutlet, and in the properties routing config, have child routes. Something like `[{ path: '', component: PropertiesComponent, children: [ { path: 'search', loadChildren: ... } ] }]`

Comment: @Gerald Chifanzwa, if I do that I lose the sub navigation menu

Comment: @NewDeveloper no you wont, your child components will be rendered within your ProductComponent below your navigation. You only lose your sub navigation if you dont specify the routes as children of the route config element with `{ path: '', component: ProductsComponent ... }`

Comment: @Gerald Chifanzwa Gotcha, looks like it worked. If you want to create an answer I can mark it.

Comment: Glad it worked. Answer posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have your routeroutlet in your properties component

```
<!--properties.component.html-->
<button [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { properties: ['searchproperties'] } }]">
   Search Properties
</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> 
<!--no name on routerOutlet-->
```

Then in your properties module routing, configure PropertiesComponent at the default route, and your SearchComponent as a child of that route, as below.

```
// properties-routing module
const routes: Routes = [
{ 
   path: '', 
   component: PropertiesComponent,
   children: [
       { 
           path: 'searchproperties', 
           loadChildren: () => import(`./searchproperties/searchproperties.module`).then(m => m.SearchpropertiesModule)
       },
       // { ...any other child routes }
   ]
},
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
}) 
export class PropertiesRouting { }
```

Comment: Hey, I had the same problem as OP and your answer solved it for me too. Thank you! What I don't understand is WHY it works. Why can't the router-outlet in the lazy-loaded module be named?

Comment: I will not tell you why, but I know that it should not be named if the `router-outlet` is within a lazy loaded route from the last `router-outlet`